# How to prove $\sup_y\left|\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n F(y|X_i)-E(F(y|X))\right|\overset{p}\to0?$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-convergence, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose we have two random variable $X$ and $Y$. The conditional CDF of $Y|X$ is defined as $F(y|X)=P(Y\le y|X)$. Let $X_1,X_2,\cdots, X_n$ be random sample of $X$.
Show that
$$\sup_y\left|\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n F(y|X_i)-E(F(y|X))\right|\overset{p}\to0.$$

---

By LLN, we can obtain that
$$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n F(y|X_i)-E(F(y|X))\overset{a.s.}\to0$$ 
My question is that how can we obtain the uniform convergence?

Comment: How do we define $P(Y\leq y \mid X)$?

Comment: $F(y|x)=F(y|X=x)=P(Y\le y|X=x)$. I think that the uniform law of large number may be applied to this result.

Comment: Here, we need to pay attention. For continuous random variable ("continuous''
means that the cumulative distribution function of the random variable
is continuous), the even $[X=x]$ has measure $0$. It is illegal
to continue to define $P\left(Y\leq y\mid X=x\right)=\frac{P\left([Y\leq y]\cap[X=x]\right)}{P([X=x])}$
because the RHS is $0/0$.

Comment: I think the conditional CDF is well defined in probability theory, for example, see https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/ma217/conddist.pdf

Comment: That the cdf F is continuous does not imply that it is absolutely continuous. Moreover, it is very easy to construct random variable X that is not discrete nor continuous.